# subtracting col2 from col1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is it possible to calculate the values of the output columns?

For example, if I have the following

```
select col1, col2
from table1
```

Without using a stored procedure, is it possible to do something like this

pseudo code

```
select col1 as figure1, col2 as figure2, figure2 - figure1
from table1
```

**EDIT 1:**

Only reason why I was trying not to do col2 - col1 was because col1 and col2 are created via calculations already, and I didn't want to double up on the calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use aliases directly. But you can use cte or subquery

```
;with cte as
(
  select
    col1 as figure1,
    col2 as figure2
  from table1
)
select
  figure1,
  figure2,
  figure2-figure1 as figure3
from cte
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do either..

```
Select col1 as figure1, col2 as figure2, (col2-col1) as figure3
from table1
```

or

```
select figure1, figure2, (figure2-figure1) as figure3
from 
(
select col1 as figure1, col2 as figure2
from table1
)
```

Figure1 and Figure2 are aliases, so they are accessible only to the query above. They are not actual columns in the table.

If this is your actual requirement, you definitely do not need stored procedures.

Comment: I haven't tried the 2nd example. But, I think that is unnecessary, just to get an alias column in the outer query. Does it have any performance issue, especially with large number of rows?

Comment: @shahkalpesh, the second code is the way to get an alias (or @Mikael Eriksson's CTE solution which is essentially the same thing). It is possible it will be faster as it only has to do the calculation once. Otherwise you need to repeat the whole calculation in the formula.

Comment: @shahkalpesh- The second example is just to show how you can access the alias columns if you need to. For this simple example, it is not necessary at all, I was just showing how your code would look if you had a complex query with aliases and wanted to access them from an outer query.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
select col1, col2, col1 - col2 
from table
```

Don't need stored proc.

This assumes both columns are of the same type, otherwise you may need to cast them beforehand. Oh, and the columns need to be of some numeric data type - subtracting text from varchars doesn't usually end well...

Comment: This will not work, the poster says that col1 and col2 are both aslo calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly.

```
select col1 as figure1, col2 as figure2, col1 - col2 as subtractions from table1
```

Comment: This will not work, the poster says that col1 and col2 are both aslo calculations.

Comment: Sorry. That was edited later so wasnt part of the original post. Yes in that case you have to go the subquery rout.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think that above will work.
However, the following will work, for which you don't need stored procedures.

```
select col1 as figure1, col2 as figure2, col1 - col2 as result 
from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the data types, but it should be possible (assuming they are ints or something you can perform your operation on):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col1-col2 as 'Variance'
FROM Mytable
Where Conditions
```

Comment: This will not work, the poster says that col1 and col2 are both aslo calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put Yes.

You can do a variety of mathematical operations with your data. You may stumble into conversion issues at times especially when you want to convert your values back to a string.

The biggest pain in the butt I have encountered is when working with decimal values, you might get conversion errors when trying to store the value in a parameter because it isn't defined as big enough to hold the result. Things to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1 as figure1, col2 as figure2, col2 - col1 as figure3 
from table1
```

will definitely do the trick, but to make things clear, is this a trick question ;-)

Comment: This will not work, the poster says that col1 and col2 are both aslo calculations.